# How to set and call private data members of multiple classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks, bank

Overview: I'm trying to create a bank account program that has multiple classes (4 to be exact). Here's the heirarchy -

> Bank
>
> > Account accounts;
>
> Account
>
> > Depositor depositor_info;
> >
> > Int Account_number;
> >
> > Double account_balance;
>
> Depositor
>
> > Name depositor_name;
> >
> > string Social Security Number;
>
> Name
>
> > String first, last;

I can set the depositor's name, and then assign depositor to an account. However I can't seem to print out the depositor's name. Here's the main testing code:

```
Account test[MAX_ACCTS];

string first = "john", last = "doe", social = "132456789";
int acctNumber = 987654;
Name name;
Depositor depositor;

name.setFirst(first); // works
name.setLast(last); // works

depositor.setName(name);  // this works
depositor.setSSN(social); // this works

test[1].setDepositor(depositor); // this also works. 

cout << test[1].getDepositor(); // Here I get an error:
no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'Depositor')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read about [mcve].and [ask] questions

Comment: By the way, did you read the error message? What word in that sentence did you not understand?

Comment: You didn't tell C++ how to print a `Depositor`. Did you mean to use `cout << test[1].getDepositor().depositor_name;`? Alternatively you can add a function that can print a `Depositor` as described for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167404/operator-overloading-ostream-istream).

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a custom `operator<<` overload for `std::ostream&` and `Depositor const&` as the arguments. C++ doesn't implicitly know how to convert your objects into text.

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, Depositor const& depositor) {
    out << depositor.getName().getLast() << ", " << depositor.getName().getFirst();
    out << "; " << depositor.getSSN();
    return out;
}
```

Obviously, you can adjust the specific behavior if simply printing the name + SSN is not the desired behavior.